# Bollinger bands in React application with a library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I am using Chart.js library in my React application.
I want to implement Bollinger Bands looking like this:

[image: Bollinger bands]

Is it possible and if so how? I have searched through issues of the repository and have not found the answer I am looking for.

If it is not possible what other library could you recommend? I have looked into:

- Highcharts
- React-charts
- react-chartjs-2
- React-financial-charts
- react-stockcharts
- Recharts

Could you direct me to the sources I need to read.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in chart.js by default, you can achieve this in 2 ways, you can write a custom inline plugin to draw it on the canvas or you can use 2 extra datasets and filter out the legend

Extra datasets example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        borderColor: 'black'
      },
      {
        label: 'boll 1',
        data: [6.6, 9, 4, 7, 0, 2],
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHoverRadius: 0,
        tension: 0.4,
        pointHitRadius: 0
      },
      {
        label: 'boll 2',
        data: [7.3, 11.5, 5.9, 9.6, 5, 11],
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointRadius: 0,
        pointHoverRadius: 0,
        fill: '-1',
        tension: 0.4,
        pointHitRadius: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          filter: (label, data) => (!label.text.includes("boll"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!